# Rotating a rectangle 360 degrees on its diagonal

Tags: geometry, rotations

The question is:
What is the 3-dimensional figure formed when a rectangle is rotated 360 degrees on its digonal? [When you rotate a square, you get a spindle, but what is it called when you rotate a rectangle?]
Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115743/question-about-a-rotating-cube can someone adapt the code provided for the cube to a rectangle and show us the picture if you have mathematica ?   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/drawing-rotated-views-while-ignoring-the-bounding-box

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a specific name, but it is similar to the [MSE question 115743](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115743)
"Question about a rotating cube". It is a symmetrical solid of revolution. The top and bottom are frustrum of cones as in a spindle and the middle is a hyperboloid of one sheet. The three sections are each ruled surfaces.